# Does filebeat add metadata while sending logs to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, systemd, filebeat

I'm trying to send systemd logs to elasticsearch via filebeat. I see the following metadata field in elasticsearch for one of the log entries.

```
"meta" : {
        "cloud" : {
          "instance_id" : "xxxxxx",
          "machine_type" : "xxxxxx",
          "instance_name" : "xxxx",
          "availability_zone" : "xxxxxx",
          "provider" : "xxxxx"
        }
      },
```

I was wondering if the above metadata field visible is added by filebeat or its a field picked up by systemd and just forwarded to elasticsearch as is by filebeat? Is there a way to check that? Or does filebeat by default add metadata to logs that it forwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does [add metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html) fields.

Look into your `filebeat.yml`, you will probably see the two lines below:

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

The `host` and `cloud` metadata are enabled per default, if you don't want those fields you just need to comment those lines.